# Background Color not assigned and Cell reuse issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have made a simple app with `UICollectionView` embedded inside `UITableViewCell`.
But when the app runs, the `UICollectionViewCell` don't get there assigned color and are later reused.

**TableViewCell** and **CollectionViewCell** are designed respectively in their nib - `CustomTableViewCell.xib` and `CustomCollectionViewCell.h`

**Cells in the same row must have same color i.e red color cells in 1st row of TableView, green color cells in 2nd row of TableView and so on.**

My code is below

**ViewController.h**

```
@interface ViewController:UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *userTableView;
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSArray* color;
@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
 [super viewDidLoad];
_color=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIColor redColor],[UIColor  greenColor],[UIColor blueColor],[UIColor purpleColor],[UIColor orangeColor],[UIColor cyanColor],[UIColor lightGrayColor],[UIColor   magentaColor], nil];
[_userTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"TVCell"];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return 8;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
CustomTableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TVCell"];
CustomCollectionViewCell *cCell=(CustomCollectionViewCell*)[cell.userCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cCell.backgroundColor=[_color objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
}
```

**CustomTableViewCell.h**

```
@interface CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell  <UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView   *userCollectionView;
@end
```

**CustomTableViewCell.m**

```
@implementation CustomTableViewCell
- (void)awakeFromNib {
[super awakeFromNib];
[_userCollectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CVCell"];
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return 20;
}
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
CustomCollectionViewCell* cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CVCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
return cell;
}
```

**Below is image of UI after running project**

[image]

How do I solve this problem? 
Please help.

**Cells in the same column must have same color i.e red color cells in 1st column of TableView, green color cells in 2nd column of TableView and so on.**

Comment: Do you want to change color for colletionviewcell's background or tableviewcell's ?

Comment: CollectionViewCell's background color should be changed. @KKRocks

Comment: then you need replace this line :  cCell.backgroundColor=[_color objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; in collectionview's cellForItemAtIndexPath instead of tableview's cellForItemAtIndexPath .

Comment: Agree with @KKRocks, and the tableView cellForRow must reloadData on its collection view.

Comment: It do work, but what I want is that each row of table view shows only cell with one color i.e. red for all cells at row 1, green for cells at row 2 and so on @KKRocks

Comment: @bhatejaud your approach is wrong.

Comment: it is the logical part . so please give explanation about that how to manage you that color .

Answer (score 0):

In your `UITableViewDelegate` method `cellForRow` register the collectionViewCell and setup its `delegate` and `datasource` then In `UICollectionViewDelegate` method `cellForItemAtIndexPath` set the background of your collectionView Cell. It will be better and easier to manage if you assign your collectionView delegate in your controller.

Hope it helps.